# Amazon Java SDK - Invoke Lambda Function

Tags: java, json, lambda, aws-lambda

I am encountering a small issue when I invoke a lambda function with json data using the Java SDK.

Here is my code

**My Pojo Class**

```
    public class MyVO implements Serializable {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3425814577032276812L;

    @JsonProperty("object_id")
    private Long objectId;
    @JsonProperty("object_name")
    private String objectName;

    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

**Code that calls Lambda Function**

```
        InvokeRequest invokeRequest = new InvokeRequest().withFunctionName(functionName).withPayload(jsonToSend);

    InvokeResult invokeResult = null;
    try {
        invokeResult = awsLambdaAsyncClient.invoke(invokeRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
        ...
    }
```

**Amazon Lambda andler Method**

```
    public LambdaResponseVO handleRequest(final MyVO input, final Context lambdaContext) {
    LOG.info("Entered handleRequest - input:{}", input);        

}
```

When I pass in the following Json - my objects in the handler print as being null

```
{"object_id":299,"object_name":"Example Schedule"}
```

However when I pass in the following json - the objects are set perfectly

```
{"objectId":299,"objectName":"Example Schedule"}
```

The Lambda handler is parsing the json based on the field names and not the jackson @JsonProperty annotations

is there anyway for me to force my lambda code to use the jackson annotations for parsing the json?

Thanks
Damien

Comment: I had this problem before too.  It appears that the Jackson parser is being overridden in Lambda with something that ignores the Jackson specific annotations.  The only way I could solve it was to move to Gson.

Comment: where did you implement the json? Was it when calling out to the lambda function? or with in the handler itself?

Comment: It was in my handler that had a custom object that I received.  I too wanted to rename fields but never figured out a way.  So I just accepted what Lambda gave me and any other JSON processing used Gson.  I'll admit I was under a time pressure and just kept going from there.

Comment: makes sense - thanks for your comments. Did you use any framework or just pure Java?

Comment: I used Gson - it allowed for field renaming easily.

Comment: did you use any Java framework like Spring Boot?

Comment: No, my Lambdas are pretty simple - mostly involved in being a front door to trigger something else.  For example, I'll respond to an IOT event and save that into DynamoDB.  Other ones are driven by time to, for example, do some database maintenance that is very simple.